# Unable to get files in Android assets directory

Tags: eclipse, android-sdk-2.3, android-assets

I am trying to find files located in assets.  I have .txt, .gif, and .db files that are there in an eclipse android project but do not display when I run the following code:

```
AssetManager am = getAssets();
try {
    String list[] = am.list("/");
    I=0;
    Str="";
    while (list[] != null) {
        Str=Str+"\r\n"+list[I];
        I++;
    }
}
catch(exception e){
}
```

I get this list:

```
AndroidManifest.xml
META-INF
assets
classes.dex
com
res
resources.arsc
```

This list does not include any of the files in assets.

Project properties is currently set to not include assets folder in the build path.  When I do include the assets folder in the build path, it gives me the same list with ".." as the first file.

I have tried changing "/" in the third line to "/assets/" but get nothing returned.

Changing the Android Project Build Target between Android 2.3.1 and Android 2.1-update1 appears to have no effect.

Is there a setting in the project properties that is required for files in assets to be included in the build?  Is there a different name for the assets directory using AssetManager?

Answer (score 1):

[list()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) takes a relative path within the assets.  Seems in your case you need to pass an empty string, am.list("")

Comment: This sort of works. I now get one of the 4 files there (txt file) but not the other 3 (.db and .gif).  I also get 'images', 'sounds', and 'webkit' - none of which are subdirectories in my assets folder.

Comment: I needed to add assets as a source to the build.  Thanks for your help.